# Selenium C# Error: System.InvalidOperationException : Could not start a new session

Tags: c#, docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bitbucket-pipelines

I have some tests that I execute against a standalone-chrome docker container through bitbucket pipelines. The tests were working fine for the last few months until this week wherein I see the below error occuring randomly for some tests:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : Could not start a new session. New session request timed out
Build info: version: '4.3.0', revision: 'a4995e2c09*'
System info: host: '288d627651eb', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.13.0-1031-aws', java.version: '11.0.15'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown (SessionNotCreated)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor executor, ICapabilities capabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at AutoTests.Resources.WebdriverFactory.Create() in /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/AutoTests/Resources/WebdriverFactory.cs:line 78
   at AutoTests.Pages.Outlook.OutlookPage.OpenOutlook() in /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/AutoTests/Pages/Outlook/OutlookPage.cs:line 64
   at AutoTests.Pages.Outlook.OutlookPage.LoginToOutlook(String emailId, String password) in /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/AutoTests/Pages/Outlook/OutlookPage.cs:line 30
   at AutoTests.Tests.DualVerificationTests.TC_03_Validate_Self_Registration__Approved() in /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/AutoTests/Tests/DualVerificationTests.cs:line 292
```

I read that it can be an issue with shm which may cause a page crash, so in the docker run command I have also set the chrome option to disable "--disable-dev-shm-usage" but still facing the issue.
Below are the chrome options I am using

```
var chromeDockerOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeDockerOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", GenericHelpers.GetAssemblyLocation());
chromeDockerOptions.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
chromeDockerOptions.AddArgument("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
chromeDockerOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads", 1);

return new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), chromeDockerOptions.ToCapabilities(), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(timeout));
```

Would appreciate if someone can help me in resolving this issue. Thanks.

Comment: can you share your docker-compose file ?

Comment: I do not have a docker-compose file as I am running the tests in bitbucket as a service against a standalone-chrome image by executing the below command. docker run --shm-size="4g" -id -p 4444:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome

Comment: Which version of Chrome and which version of ChromeDriver are you using? Browsers like to auto-update themselves.

Comment: The tests are failing randomly on Chrome version 103. Works fine on 102 though. Looks like a problem with Chrome version 103.

Comment: That depends. The Chrome and ChromeDriver major versions needs to match. For example, if you are running Chrome 103.x, then ChromeDriver must be 103.x. Maybe try updating ChromeDriver to a newer patch version? Are you sure you are still on Chrome 103? Chrome likes to auto-update.